# MySQL 5.7 No directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: server, mysql

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I can't find any solution to this (maybe small) issue:

I just made a fresh install of mysql-server 5.7 on a 14.04 server.
Every time the MySQL service starts, I get this error:

```
root@xxx:/etc/mysql# service mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL Community Server 5.7.11
...
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.11 is stopped
 * Re-starting MySQL Community Server 5.7.11
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
..
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.11 is started
```

What does that mean? Do I have to set a home directory to the user "mysql"? (and if so, what is the best choice? /home/mysql??) Now it's to /nonexistent:

```
mysql:x:110:106:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

but I have another machine with the same /nonexistent, and it doesn't show any error...

Comment: /var/log/mysql ;-) see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/539440/mysql-wont-start-after-installation-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-1

Comment: ok, in my case it started and seems to work fine, it just shows just that notice

Answer (score 48):

Having same issue to get rid of this error i did the following

1. Stop MYSQL service:

   `sudo service mysql stop`
2. Change home directory of mysql from nonexistent to original directory where it is supposed to be:

   `sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql`

Now start mysql server again with:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

The error message has disappeared. Still why this happen is unknown.

Comment: It might be a work around but I would disagree with this. /home/ is for users. Not for creating a place for dummy users that are needed for security/permissions/whatever. The person suggesting /home/mysql and creating an actual mysql user should be **seriously reprimanded**.

Comment: /var/lib o /var/log? Anyway, that directory doesn't seem to be getting populated with any data

Comment: yea this is a workaround let  me know when you find a solution.

Comment: According to [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/755763/mysql-nonexistent-home-vs-no-directory-logging-in-with-home), Red Hat has mysql home directory set to `/var/lib/mysql`. So this seems ok....

Comment: For what it's worth, I got this error when I was running mysql in Windows WSL. The error stopped happening after I quit mysqld.exe on Windows. Port 3306 was claimed by the Windows process.

Comment: Same for me was getting in WSL there was  a process with mysqlid quit it and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem inside an Ubuntu 16.04 container

Comment: I had to stop Docker which obviously was using the 3306 port

Comment: This worked for me to fix the problem in WSL, this should appear in Google top results

Comment: This worked for WSL :D

Answer (score 1):

I would furtrher suggest a permanent solution, if it always run from the same dir as I suppose it should why not edit the user mysql in /etc/passwd:

```
mysql:x:106:111:MySQL Server,,,:/var/lib/mysql/:/bin/false
```