# Mysql show error /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: DirectoryWSL: Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I install mysql in WSL: Ubuntu 18.04
when I restart mysql `sudo service mysql restart` show error:

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 20: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent
```

then try to modify file /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh

```
# Check if we have HOME folder
if [[ "${HOME}" == "/" ]]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

but it is not working....and show error:

```
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
-su: 2: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: [[: not found
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 23: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent
```

How to fix this issue?
thank you....

Comment: This post suggesting `usermod` fixed it for me
https://askubuntu.com/questions/737903/mysql-5-7-no-directory-logging-in-with-home

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find the file `.cache/wslu/integration` in `/home/<your_name>/`. There, you can modify the file `/etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh` like this:

```
HOME=/home/your_name
```

and remove the checking of `${HOME}`